# Wordpress Impreza theme and Mega Menu error to resolve

Tags: wordpress, w3c-validation, megamenu

I am trying to resolve the issue of Impreza theme with mega menu
The issue is that we endeavour to ensure that our site https://www.aleaitsolutions.com/ only uses valid HTML (as we are a development company that is commercially important to us). When we used the industry standard W3 Validator service our Home Page is now only showing one HTML error. This relates to the illegal inclusion of DIVs within an Un-ordered List. It appears to us that this issue has been introduced by Mega Menu.

Details of the error can be found here:
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aleaitsolutions.com%2F

The error message is as follows:

```
Error: Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
From line 210, column 1818; to line 210, column 1878

e hidden"><div id="mega-menu-wrap-us_main_menu" class="mega-menu-wrap"><div c

Contexts in which element div may be used:
Where flow content is expected.
As a child of a dl element.
Content model for element ul:
Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.
```

Now when I checked this to resolve the issue at my end, below is the details after applying the changes

Below is the structure
We have ul li and  under  li I was able to remove the div under li from "widget.manager_class.php" from my Impreza theme

Now, I want to remove the  under  which is "

Below is the code for your reference

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
 'theme_location' => $menu_location,
 //'container' => '',
 //'container_class' => 'w-nav-list',
 //'walker' => new US_Walker_Nav_Menu,
 //'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
 //'fallback_cb' => FALSE,
) );
echo '</ul>';
echo '<div class="w-nav-options hidden"';
echo us_pass_data_to_js( array(
 'mobileWidth' => intval( $mobile_width ),
 'mobileBehavior' => intval( $mobile_behavior ),
) );
echo '></div>';
echo '</nav>';
```

Though the  is closed before the div.

Please check this and guide me for some solution. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Rob, I have updated my question, could you please have a look and guide me